# Using 360 images as background to take pictures in

Tags: android, arcore

I have been working on an app that can take 360 images, however, I want to do more than just taking a 360 picture. I want this application to be able to use that (or any other 360 images) as a background for other people to take pictures in; for instance, if you have a 360 picture of a mountain or a resort someone should be able to take that picture load it in the app and use that 360 image to take a picture (while standing in front of a green screen to make it easier). So the app should treat the 360 image as an AR object.
I searched extensively for something or somehow to do this and I ended up empty handed .. if anyone can help me with this I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is no code in here to debug. Please see the help center for example  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This looks too broad also. It should be done in the context of some libray or framework for that type of things but I can't help you here. I am sure you aren't the first using AR...

Comment: Thank you. I've read those rules, but I couldn't find anything at all not even one topic that talks about this subject this is why I can't post any lines of codes or anything since I'm also new to the subject and I hoped that someone experience will at least guide me to where and how can I start with implementing such feature..

Comment: A little search brings up the obvious: https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/concepts, but I don't know if you can do something like that. Maybe someone using ARCore can help you. I am adding the tag and upvoting this.

Comment: Is possible to do something like this by definition, but would be nice to see what are you trying so we can help. Think about a 3D object with the image inside that you need to anchor so you can be inside this object.

Comment: @Canato I'm trying to create an application when you open it there will be a big sphere (textured with 360 video) around you that you can navigate through it with AR and then I'm trying to also display what the camera sees in real life on lets say a flat surface infront of the camera that moves around with you so you can take pictures of someone with green screen behind them and then eliminate the green-screen so its just like the taken picture of that person had that 360 video background.. this may not be very clear but I tried my best ..

Comment: @Lawchak I understood, and keep my answer. Would be nice see something (like your code) and you can do this with a anchor. don't need a green-screen

Comment: @Canato I initially only have created the sphere, textured it, and created a portal so it gives you an effect that you can move from the real world and step into the virtual environment  an move around using AR, I can post the scripts if you want. Also about the anchor you are talking about can you elaborate more please? this is the only point I'm stuck in.. and how would you remove the extra background without using a green screen? can we communicate somewhere else so I can understand you better?